# Github No access to code for app integrations

Tags: github, sonarcloud

I am trying to setup SonarCloud for Github, and getting the following issue (see screenshot).

I know that github recently changed some of its permission models, so how can i allow an app access to code?

The lead up issue statement is that I want to write an integration via webhook that will also need to have access to code, so would the solution to the above mentioned issue resolve that, or is that a different permission model?

[image: permission]

Comment: This should be under the repo contents section under the permissions settings page. https://developer.github.com/apps/managing-github-apps/editing-a-github-app-s-permissions/

Comment: @osowskit this is great for the second half of my question, but how about the first half?

Comment: Their app likely doesn't require access to your source code or they need to modify their application to request these permissions. Given they don't ask for the permissions, you should check you are installing what you think you are installing